# How to run ./Configure to compile an application on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, unix

I am trying to install this application on my Mac and according to the readme file I should start with ./configure command. But if I do that I get a

```
./configure: command not found
```

error.

This is the application I am trying to install:
http://cgit.sukimashita.com/ideviceinstaller.git/

Comment: Do you have xcode installed on your machine?

Comment: Yes, I do have XCode

Answer (score 3):

Please try to run "autogen.sh" first. This will create **configure** file. And then try to run "./configure".

Answer (score 3):

You simply need to reinstall autoconf (I am using Mac Os)

use this command and try again,  it should work

```
brew install autoconf
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to (install and) run `autoconf` to generate the `configure` script.

Maybe submit a bug report about the incomplete building instructions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to build this from a distribution, as opposed to running it from a checkout, then you *should* have a file `configure` in the unpacked distribution.  The distribution appears to be available from the library's [home page](http://www.libimobiledevice.org); your link pointed to the source repository.

You need to run that command `./configure` while you are in the directory which contains that file (the `.` in the command means 'run the script in *this* directory').

Building from a repository is generally more complicated than building from a distribution, because the person rolling the distribution has to perform steps such as generating this `configure` script (as the other answers discuss), and possibly generating other code.  You should build from a pre-prepared distribution unless you have a particular reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
chmod 777 configure
./configure
```

never use `sudo ./configure`

I solve this problem on mac

xampp  php7.0.* when I try to install php intl

but if fail to install it.

Comment: Whatever you are hoping to acomplish, **`chmod 777` is *wrong* and a *serious security* problem.** You should revert to sane permissions ASAP (probably 755 for your use case) and read up on the semantics of the mode bits before attempting to apply them, let alone advise others on their use. In so many words, making system files writable for all uses is an creating a vector for privilege escalation - if you have a break-in, the hacker will pwn your box because of this mistake.